# agora.io Android SDK: how to get all remote users "uid"s

Tags: android, sdk, agora.io

I could't find any way to get the uids of all the remote users in a video chat (not a live stream). Is there a way or workaround to get the remote users' uids?

Note that I couldn't rely on "onUserJoined()" or `onRemoteVideoStateChanged()`, because sometimes the current user joins late or some remote users mute their video all the time, so there are sometimes some uids missing.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The onUserJoined method should be able to return the existing users in the channel when the current user joins the channel. Here is the API doc for that: https://docs.agora.io/en/Interactive%20Broadcast/API%20Reference/java/classio_1_1agora_1_1rtc_1_1_i_rtc_engine_event_handler.html#aa466d599b13768248ac5febd2978c2d3

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I have tried the `onUserJoined(int uid, int elapsed)`. The problem is that when I join a channel late, and other users are already in the channel, the `onUserJoined()` method won't be called for these already joined users. Is there a way to get the uids of these joined users?

Comment: It should be called. Same as the onRemoteVideoStateChanged(). When the user joins the channel and there are other existing users in the channel, these methods will be triggered with the remote user's uid in the parameter.

Comment: when other users joined with their video muted all the time, the `onRemoteVideoStateChanged()` is not called. It's only called when other people un-mute their video.

Comment: onUserJoined() is still not called when user is the last person join the channel, so I still don't know the uids of other remote users

Comment: onUserJoined() should return the existing uid in the channel. If not, please file a jira ticket to Agora here: https://agora-ticket.agora.io/